# How To Loop Through Multiple Pages And Open Links At The Same Time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently trying to figure out how to loop through a set of studios on a fitness class website.

On the search results page of this website, it lists 50  studios on each page and there are about 26 pages. https://classpass.com/search if you want to take a look.

My code parses the search result page, and selenium gets the link for each studio on the page(In my full code selenium opens goes to the link and scrapes data on the page).

After looping through all the results on page 1, I want to click the next page button and repeat on results page 2. I get the error  `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:` but I know the element is definitely on the results page and can be clicked. I tested this with a simplified script to confirm.

What could I be doing wrong? I've tried many suggestions but none have worked so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as browser_wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import re
import csv

# initialize the chrome browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver')

# URL
class_pass_url = 'https://www.classpass.com'

# Create file and writes the first row, added encoding type as write was giving errors
#f = open('ClassPass.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
#headers = 'URL, Studio, Class Name, Description, Image, Address, Phone, Website, instagram, facebook, twitter\n'
#f.write(headers)

# classpass results page
page = "https://classpass.com/search"

browser.get(page)

# Browser waits

browser_wait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "line")))

# Scrolls to bottom of page to reveal all classes
# browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# Extract page source and parse
search_source = browser.page_source
search_soup = soup(search_source, "html.parser")

pageCounter = 0
maxpagecount = 27

# Looks through results and gets link to class page
studios = search_soup.findAll('li', {'class': '_3vk1F9nlSJQIGcIG420bsK'})

while (pageCounter < maxpagecount):

    search_source = browser.page_source
    search_soup = soup(search_source, "html.parser")
    studios = search_soup.findAll('li', {'class': '_3vk1F9nlSJQIGcIG420bsK'})

    for studio in studios:

        studio_link = class_pass_url + studio.a['href']
        browser.get(studio_link)

        browser_wait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "line")))

        

    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Search_Results"]/div[1]/div/div/nav/button[2]')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return to the main page before finding the next page button. You could solve the problem by the replacing the following code. This code will initially collect all page's studio url.

```
studios = search_soup.findAll('li', {'class': '_3vk1F9nlSJQIGcIG420bsK'})
```

to

```
studios = []
for page in range(num_pages):
    studios.append(search_soup.findAll('li', {'class': '_3vk1F9nlSJQIGcIG420bsK'}))

    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Search_Results"]/div[1]/div/div/nav/button[2]')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

and remove the code clicking the next page button element.

Comment: Hi Thank you. I tried that but it only goes as far as to the next. Not sure why it's doing that, but i'll keep trying

Comment: Hi @krenerd, can you possibly do me the favour of adding the lines you said to my initial code in an answer? I'm just not sure whether i've changed my code accordingly. I would greatly appreciate it.